# Manipulating style with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why I cannot manipulate the style of .special in my code.  I'm sure it's something simple, but it's not working.

```
<h1>I am an h1!</h1>
<p id="first" class="special">Hello</p>
<p class="special">Goodbye</p>
<p>Hi Again</p>
<p id="last">Goodbye Again</p>


var x = document.getElementsByClassName("special");
x.style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `for of` statement to iterate the collection you get back.

```
for (const s of document.getElementsByClassName("special")) {
  s.style.color = "blue";
}
```

---

And I would personally use `querySelectorAll` instead, since it's more general purpose, and can fetch by class just as easily.

```
for (const s of document.querySelectorAll(".special")) {
  s.style.color = "blue";
}
```

---

Lastly, if all `.special` classes should get that style, it would seem like you could just add it to your CSS instead.

```
.special {
  color: blue;
}
```

This will depend on other logic that you may have not included in the question though. Even then, you may be able to get away with adding another class, maybe even to some ancestor element.

Comment: If I wanted to select all elements from a class, do I have to use a loop to do so?

Comment: @mrwallace3: To operate on them you need some sort of loop. Even if you use some 3rd party API that lets you call methods directly on the collection, it's still using a loop under the hood. It could be that having to operate on each one could be avoided, but it depends on exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a collection not just one object. So you need to loop through them and apply the color to it. Below is a sample example with mouse events.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var hiClass = document.getElementsByClassName("special");
    
    document.getElementById('A').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        changeColor(hiClass, 'red');
    });
    document.getElementById('A').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        changeColor(hiClass, 'blue');
    });
    
    document.getElementById('B').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        changeColor(hiClass, 'blue');
    });
    
    document.getElementById('B').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        changeColor(hiClass, 'red');
    });
}
function changeColor(coll, color){
   
    for(var i=0, len=coll.length; i<len; i++)
    {
        coll[i].style["background-color"] = color;
    }
}
```

```css
.a {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.b {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:10px;
}
th {
    padding:20px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="A" >a</th>
        <th id="B" >b</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<h1>I am an h1!</h1>
<p id="first" class="special">Hello</p>
<p class="special">Goodbye</p>
<p>Hi Again</p>
<p id="last">Goodbye Again</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of *all* elements with class "special", not just one (because there can be multiple elements with the same class name).
If you want to get the first element with class "special", do this instead:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("special");
x[0].style.color = "blue";
```

To change the style of all elements with class "special", you  can use a classic for loop:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("special");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` is returning as an array of objects. You could use jQuery to return a list of more manipulable objects, or do a count on the return, and iterate through the array, setting properties on each item as you go.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object. You need to reference it as such.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("special")[0]; //Get the first element with the class name
x.style.color = "blue";
```